# Laravel Eloquent "Call to a member function pluck() on null" error

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have problem with Eloquent relationship. I have a user (User::class) and I have a group (Group::class). An User belongs to a Group (because it is a class for student at school).

Method at User class:

```
public function group()
{
    $this->belongsTo(Group::class, 'group_id');
}
```

Getting it at view by:

```
{{ $user->group()->pluck('name') }}
```

But the error is:

> Call to a member function pluck() on null (View: C:\XAMPP\htdocs\vados\resources\views\users\index.blade.php)

I have no idea why this relationship doesn't work. Any suggestions? I wish you a nice Sunday.

Answer (score 3):

It is because the `group()` method **does not return**  anything. To solve this, add `return` statement

```
public function group()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(Group::class, 'group_id');
}
```

Comment: No, please! :) Glad to help